# PostGIS import shapefile Error

Tags: postgis, shapefile, import, gui

I am using PostGIS GUI to import shapefile. The connection is good. While I successfully imported the Alabama table. I got the following error when I tried to import the other two shapefiles. I imported those files separately. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete @Ian Turnon's answer, you have **four modes** (use the dropdown menu) :

- Create
- Append
- Delete
- Prepare

[image]

You can use append if you want to add rows to your existing table. Otherwise I advise you to delete your layer first in your database and then use the Create mode.

Comment: Hi thanks. But does that mean I am unable to create two tables in one batch using the PostGIS GUI tool?

Comment: you can create as many tables as you want but before deleting the tables with the same name in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked the program to create a new table but it already exists. I'm not familiar with the tool you are using but there is probably a check box about creating or appending the data and you need to change that.

Comment: clicking on the "create" text brings a drop-down box allowing one to `append` the data to and existing table, or to `delete` it first